# VerifyError Exception on Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, verifyerror

I'm running my app on Android Studio 1.3.2, and getting an exception that I can't get through. I've been searching on google for hours and didn't find the solution.

```
java.lang.VerifyError: org/apache/http/conn/ssl/DefaultHostnameVerifier
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder.build(HttpClientBuilder.java:944)
        at com.romi.expensemanager.OCRServiceAPI.sendImage(OCRServiceAPI.java:62)
        at com.romi.expensemanager.OCRServiceAPI.convertToText(OCRServiceAPI.java:44)
        at com.romi.expensemanager.Main$1.run(Main.java:68)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

I add external jars: 
httpclient-4.5.jar, httpcore-4.4.1.jar, httpmime-4.5.jar.

My build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.romi.expensemanager"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
compile files('libs/achartengine-1.1.0.jar')
compile files('libs/picasso-2.5.2.jar')
compile project(':httpclient-4.5')
compile project(':httpcore-4.4.1')
compile project(':httpmime-4.5')
}
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: where did you add the Jars in the project ?

Comment: I add them in a module.

Comment: yes i know, OK you must add them under libs folder and than richt click on it and "add as library", it must add a line in your gradle file "compile file(libs/your jar name"

Comment: I done that, and received the same error :(

Comment: I succeed to solve this by adding the jars: httpcore-4.0-beta2.jar, httpclient-4.0-beta2.jar, httpmime-4.1.2.jar. Thank you Fakher for trying to help me :)

Comment: not at all :) it seems that the jars has dependencies, so when you added these jars every thing has gone OK